# topological  B model

Tags: topological-quantum-field-theory, quantum-field-theory, reference-request, soft-question

The topological A model was constructed by Witten in Comm. Math. Phys. Volume 118, Number 3 (1988), 411-449. I am looking for the original paper where topological B model was first introduced. I am reading another paper of Witten, Topological Field theory and mirror manifolds, where he discussed the B model, but I am looking for first construction of B model.

Can you also suggest some other references about the modern treatment of B model. I know Kevin Costello has done some work in this direction.
Thanks.

Comment: I think the relevant physics reference is the paper by Bershadsky-Cecotti-Ooguri-Vafa http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9309140 . I once asked a similar question on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8692/higher-genus-closed-string-b-model Zaslow and Ben-Zvi's answers there should be useful to you.

Comment: @ Kevin - I looked at your question and the answers by Zaslow n Ben-Zvi, but this is not exactly what I am looking for. In Witten's paper Mirror manifolds and Topological Field theory http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9112056, he gives two topological sigma models, A and B model. I found A model in Witten's other paper, topological sigma model. But I didn't find B-model any where. I am looking for the simplest B-model like the one Witten constructed in his paper.
I find answers to most of my questions in your earlier questions.
Thanks.

Comment: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/B-model#References